# Instead of using several if statements I want to use a boolean algebra,

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, boolean, algebra

I want to use boolean algebra instead of several conditionals, for example

```
def boo(x,y):
    if x==3 and y==1: return 4
    if x==3 and y==4: return 1
    if x==4 and y==1: return 2
    if x==4 and y==2: return 1
    if x==5 and y==1: return 3
```

what I want to do is

```
def simple(x,y):
    return x#y
```

and there are total 12 equations, I just want to directly return (x#y) where # is a boolean operator. I did this to a smaller problem where I luckily found out a relation. I want to do the same in this case also, how do I proceed with it?

Does this have any performance gains, because its not going through several if conditionals?
Is this normal practice?

sample:

```
 x    y   output
 1    2     3
 1    3     2
 1    4     5
 1    5     4
```

here a simple bitwise xor gate will do

```
def(x,y): return x^y
```

Comment: Could you give more details as to the nature of your relation? It's tough to say how to mathematically optimize the representation of a problem without knowing much about its constraints. There could be a much more elegant way to do this than using a nested `dictionary`, but as is often the case with toy problems, we'd need to understand exactly what you can and can't expect.

Comment: i'm looking for a general procedure of doing this using bit wise operations.. i remember doing this sort of problem in an undergraduate electronics class.. ill update the question with a smaller example.. my gut feeling says there must be some procedure to go backwards and find the relation.. i'm just curious.. looks like using a dictioary is more elegant way in normal cases

Comment: I can't begin to imagine how you expect to use boolean algebra when your inputs are not booleans. As for how to find the relation, well... if you don't know the relation, then how do you know the correct answer for 12 separate inputs?

Comment: see smaller example, i dont know how to ask the question formally, i mean using the correct technical words

Comment: i searched a little bit found out that this is done using [karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). i remember doing this in a class.. doing this here is bit of a stretch.. but ill try doing this and put it in the question, atleast it looks interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether trying to find a terser expression of the above logic would lead to more readable code; probably not. But you can rework the logic as-is to a more mathematical formulation:

```
def boo(x, y):
    p = (x, y)
    return (1 if p in ((3, 4), (4, 2)) else
            2 if p == (4, 1) else
            3 if p == (5, 1) else
            4 if p == (3, 1) else
            None)
```

Another option is to use a dictionary:

```
def boo(x, y):
    return {(3,4):1, (4,2):1, (4,1):2, (5,1):3, (3,1):4}.get((x, y), None)
```

If you know that all values will match the specified cases, you can write `[(x, y)]` instead of `.get((x, y), None)`.

Comment: actually there are 12 relations, so using a dictionary is a cleaner way

Answer (score 2):

You can find the right expression that yields the same values as your conditionals, but such code becomes harder to read and maintain.

A better solution is to use a nested list or dictionary which you can index with input values. This way you turn code into data which is a clear and fast representation of your mapping and which can be readily understood and easily modified in the future.

Comment: this is in a puzzle problem, no one is going to read it except for me.. using a dictionary makes sense thanks.. but i'm also curious how to find out the relation

Comment: If you're really bent on doing it then you have a few possibilities. One involves taking all the conditions, turning them into integers with `int()`, multiplying by the expected result and summing over all alternatives. Only one alternative will yield a non-zero result. Another way is to exploit polynomials. You'd search for a polynomial that yields the right result for each input. You'd start this by writing a system of simultaneous equations for polynomial coefficients and then you would write an expression that uses the coefficients to compute the result. Dictionary is your friend though!

Comment: i remember doing this sort of problem in which where you have eight bits of input and from the expected output, you design a logical gate.. so that's why i asked this question in the firstplace.. i came across this in a puzzle which looked like a straight forward problem and i couldn't think of optimizing it any other way :(

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using dictionaries. You could perhaps make a dictionary of dictionaries, and have your function retrieve values through the dictionary.

```
def boo(x,y):
    if x==3 and y==1: return 4
    if x==3 and y==4: return 1
    if x==4 and y==1: return 2
    if x==4 and y==2: return 1
    if x==5 and y==1: return 3

def boodict(x,y):
    d1 = {3: {1:4, 4:1} ,4: {1:2, 2:1},5: {1:3}}
    try:
        value = d1[x][y]
    except KeyError:
        value = None
    return value
```